# Concatenating strings in Python using multiple np.where

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I'm trying to create data keys to be used by a different program in python/pandas and am having real issues concatenating strings.

To build up the key I need to take adjusted values of existing columns in a dataframe (or lists), so I started as follows:

```
df_mpf['DATAKEY'] = np.where(df_mpf['SEX']==1,'M','F').astype(str)
```

This works fine.

I then checked whether using + would work to concat them together by doubling up the code:

```
df_mpf['DATAKEY'] = np.where(df['SEX']==1,'M','F').astype(str) + np.where(df['SEX']==1,'M','F').astype(str)
```

This fails, giving me the following error:

```
UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U1'), dtype('<U1')) -> dtype('<U1')
```

I can use + to add something which isn't an np.where whether it's from a list or a column without issue:

```
 df_mpf['DATAKEY'] = np.where(df_mpf['SEX']==1,'M','F').astype(str) + TERM_Y.astype(str) + df_mpf['AGE'].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have two numpy arrays, which are [harder](/q/9958506/16343464) to concatenate than Series.

Use Series:

```
s = pd Series(np.where(df_mpf['SEX']==1,'M','F').astype(str), index=df.index)
df_mpf['DATAKEY'] = s + s
```

Or, without numpy:

```
s = df_mpf['SEX'].eq(1).map({True: 'M', False: 'F'})
```

Or, is "SEX" contains only 0/1 for F/M

```
s = df_mpf['SEX'].map({0: 'F', 1: 'M'})
```

*NB. The array + Series works, because of the Series.*